# Spring Cloud Stream application web interface

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

is it possible to create a web interface to a spring-cloud-stream application ?

Many source (file, http, ftp) send data to an application to transform it in a common format, and to reduce development i was thinking to create a web interface where users could easily configure data transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [Spring Cloud Data Flow](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/); perhaps the [drag & drop visual designer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#dashboard) is what you're looking for.

The designer also provides a easy mechanism to override app specific properties, including how you'd transform the incoming payload using SpEL expressions.

Comment: I've already used the visual designer and properties panel in other module, but I was thinking in something more complex: an application where users can write and test their transformation script or use a graphical tool to simplify this process, like karma http://usc-isi-i2.github.io/karma/.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Have a look at [scriptable-transform-processor](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/scriptable-transform). This allows you to write transformation logic in a few languages using the code-mirror plugin. We have plans to add "develop-dryrun-verify" focused UI support in SCDF.